# Update div with html from ajax call in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, innerhtml

I'm trying to add data from an ajax call into a div on my page. The following works fine in webkit browsers, but fails in IE -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add_to_cart',
    data: {'item_id': item_id},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#cart_summary').html(data);
    }
)};
```

My html is as follows:

```
<div id="cart_summary">
    <a class='link_to_cart' href="/cart/">
        <span> CART &#40;5&#41; &pound;1054.75 </span>
        <img id="cart_icon" src="/static/images/cart_icon.tiff">
    </a>
</div>
```

I've tried dropping the jQuery `.html()` call and using

```
var cartSummary = document.getElementById('cart_summary');
cartSummary.innerHTML = data;
```

But this fails too (looking at the result of cartSummary.innerHTML in the IE debugger shows the html I want, but it's not showing on the page).

I've also tried various combinations of jQuery's `.remove()` `.text()` and `.append()` to no avail.

Comment: Does it display an error of some kind in the console?

Comment: no, nothing in the console.

Comment: do you have a link to the page?

Comment: I've added a link in the body of my question (I'm a bit paranoid so I don't really want links to my dev server floating round the interweb - I can delete the link from my question but not my comments)

Comment: @AidanEwen Try adding this in your code `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});` - IE has issues with caching and usually setting the cache to false for ajax calls will fix that

Comment: Thanks wirey, I tried adding cache:false to $.ajaxSetup(). That hasn't made any difference.

Comment: I've removed the web link due to an unresolved (and unrelated) bug on the public dev site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the problem. I'd written a dodgy django template tag that was throwing out an unclosed `<a>` tag. Internet explorer was handling this (very) strangely and making a big mess of the dom.

The outcome of this was that I had two `<div id="cart_summary">` elements (only on IE - I never worked out why). As you can imagine, this was creating problems for `document.getElementById('cart_summary')` and `$('#cart_summary')`.

The solution was to remove the duplicate element id.

(Big thanks to Palash Mondal, rcdmk, Explosion Pills, WebweaverD and Wirey, for taking the time to look into my problem).

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

**jQuery Ajax Error Handling Function**

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

After adding it, call your ajax function and you will get the error details!

Comment: Thanks but my ajax call is not the issue. (a look at my data variable confirms that).

Comment: Try to put `console.log(data);` in success func(). what is the value like? Is it json, string or int?

Comment: it's a string  - <a class='link_to_cart' href="/cart/">
<span> CART &#40;7&#41; &pound;1474.65 </span>
<img id="cart_icon" src="/static/images/cart_icon.tiff">
</a>

Comment: My code works fine in webkit browsers. Its just IE that's playing up.

Comment: I tested this in IE and I am getting error like `errorThrown - "Internal Server Error"`

Comment: I've debuged the JS in the IE9 dev tools, putting a breakpoint in the error callback, gives-me the errorThrown = "FORBIDDEN". I've also saw that the token variable used in this call is null.

Comment: My bad, I've got an another unresolved and unrelated bug. I've removed my web link from the question. On my local server it's an HTTP200 with the string above.